# How to debug when a router refuses to route for one specific device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Sometimes one device on my network cannot access Internet or even get as far as the immediate gateway after router. The problem is OS independent since it happens on both Linux & Windows. I observed following symptoms:

- I can access router without problems, signal is good.
- When I try to traceroute the `8.8.8.8` the router hop is shown but all other timeouts.
- I can access `8.8.8.8` from all other devices and from router internal tool.
- All DHCP/ARP tables look ok (MAC etc. matches)
- Wireshark shows that packets are sent to `8.8.8.8` but no response is coming back (including ICMP).

Initially the problem was gone after few minutes. However today the problem persisted through the reboots of both device and router. When I tried to reserve address and reboot (as instructed to make change take effect) the device refused to connect. However when I set the static IP it started working. How should I approach debugging?

Comment: Have you tried "factory resetting" the router?

Comment: Can you ping this computer from other computers within the same LAN as the problem occures?

Comment: @user3767013 IIRC I could but I will check next time.